# Vue components prop types not working (configuration issue?)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using Vue (version 3.3 if that matters). I can't seem to figure out how to get typing constraints to matter at build time at all.

I am aware that there are several different ways of attaching prop type metadata to a component, it seems that Vue has their own historical implementation of prop type logic and the TypeScript stuff came later as an adapter.  But I don't *think* my issue is related to that, I'm pretty sure I just have something missing in some configuration file somewhere.

Here's a sample component I've written (`Test.vue`):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {type PropType} from 'vue'

defineProps({
    foo: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    }
})

// I have also tried the following 2 and I seem to get the same behavior:

// defineProps({
//     foo: String as PropType<string>
// });

// defineProps<{foo: string}>();

</script>

<template>
    <div> Hello {{ foo }} </div>
    <!-- The above 'foo' is properly typed and has autocomplete and everything. -->
</template>
```

That all seems to work internally.  But when I try to use the component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Test from './Test.vue';
</script>

<template>
    <div> Some test components: </div>
    <!-- These work fine: -->
    <Test foo="World" />
    <Test :foo="'World'" />

    <!-- These give a runtime warning but nothing at compile time: -->
    <Test :foo="42" />
    <Test />
    <Test :foo="{ some: 'other_data_structure' }" />

    <!-- Even a built-in component doesn't give any compile time warning -->
    <Transition :name="42"/>
</template>
```

I think something in my IDE setup or `package.json` or something is misconfigured and it's not linking things together properly.  In the above file, both `Test` and `Transition` are typed as `any`.

I'm using VS Code with extensions:

- TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar)
- Vue Language Features (Volar)

I've disabled the built-in TypeScript extension as described [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode)).

ESLint is enabled and is coming back empty.  The project is coming from [the standard Vue scaffolder](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application).

I've put together a repo with [my package.json](https://github.com/JonLoesch/vue-test/blob/main/package.json) and [my vite.config](https://github.com/JonLoesch/vue-test/blob/main/vite.config.ts) and whatever else files are in there.  It has more than is necessary to reproduce this issue and is unfortunately non-minimal but I'm not sure *where* the problem is or what to isolate it down to.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html . Did you try to use vue-tsc? Your config matters and it's unknown. Did you try to use vue-tsc?

Comment: Are you aware that Vite does not perform any type checking during build? Have a look at the docs for the [reasoning behind it and what you can do](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript)

Comment: `pnpm exec vue-tsc --noEmit` finds nothing.  I am not sure the best way to upload the config without uploading a whole repo, so I made a one-off github repo with just this issue.  Sorry, I should have done that to start :(

Comment: I am aware that Vite does no type checking by default (good thought though).  I believe the issues isn't that type checking isn't happening, it's that after importing a Vue component into another file (or even using a built in Vue component) all the components seem to be `any`